# GSP- formatDate tag issue handling null date

Tags: grails-2.0, gsp

I used a collection of DATE field from Controller to GSP using the tag - 
But at times there are blanks and invalid data and it throws up an error. How should I handle this NULL pointer??

Code < g:formatDate format="yyyy-MM-dd" date="$ {objectInstance?.expiryDate} "/>

I also tried using this -- ${objectInstance?.expiryDate?.format("MM/dd/yyyy")} , but no luck. Thanks in Anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vignesh,

Here are a couple of potential solutions (assuming that you would be ok with showing nothing or some alternate text when the date is null):

```
${try{objectInstance?.expiryDate?.format('MM/dd/yyyy')}catch(e){''}}
```

Or, you could handle this in the controller (my preferred method) using the same code as a above without the ${} wrapping it and set it into a model property.

```
[expiryDateFormatted: try{objectInstance?.expiryDate?.format('MM/dd/yyyy')}catch(e){''}]
```

Give those a try and see if they will work for you.

After speaking with Vignesh it turns out that expiryDate is actually a string and not a date.  Below is a solution that would work for a string value.

```
${try{new Date().parse('yyyy-MM-dd', objectInstance?.expiryDate).format('MM/dd/yyyy')}catch(e){''}}
```

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for your response. The value that coming from Controller is String - objectInstance?.expiryDate.

Comment: Thanks Steve your solutions and help me alot

Answer (score 0):

in the GSP you can also use formatDate in this way:

```
${ g.formatDate(format:'yyyy-MM-dd', date: objectInstance?.expiryDate ) }
```

when `objectInstance?.expiryDate` is `null` it will just render a blank instead of returning an error